# PHP Pagination - All pages appearing on one page

Tags: php, pagination

I have the code below and the problem is that I am trying to get it to paginate. I would like to have a dropdown where by you can choose the page to navigate to. This code right now is showing all the pages on one page (See picture here http://www.cfbangor.com/pagination.png). I Would greatly appreciate any guidance to accomplish this task.

```html
<?php
// List all the videos in the KMC, a "page" at a time
//
// BUGS: Used $entry->dataUrl (original uploaded video) because $entry->downloadUrl doesn't work
// for the default samples in the SaaS accounts.....!
// Where are the downloadUrls for the default samples in the account?
// Your Kaltura partner credentials
define("PARTNER_ID", "xxxxxx");
define("ADMIN_SECRET", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
define("USER_SECRET", "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
require_once "KalturaClient.php";
$user = "SomeoneWeKnow";
$kconf = new KalturaConfiguration(PARTNER_ID);
// If you want to use the API against your self-hosted CE,
// go to your KMC and look at Settings -> Integration Settings to find your partner credentials
// and add them above. Then insert the domain name of your CE below.
// $kconf->serviceUrl = "http://www.mySelfHostedCEsite.com/";
$kclient = new KalturaClient($kconf);
$ksession = $kclient->session->start(ADMIN_SECRET, $user, KalturaSessionType::ADMIN, PARTNER_ID);
if (!isset($ksession)) {
 die("Could not establish Kaltura session. Please verify that you are using valid Kaltura partner credentials.");
}
$kclient->setKs($ksession);
// Set the response format
// KALTURA_SERVICE_FORMAT_JSON json
// KALTURA_SERVICE_FORMAT_XML xml
// KALTURA_SERVICE_FORMAT_PHP php
$kconf->format = KalturaClientBase::KALTURA_SERVICE_FORMAT_PHP;
$kfilter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter();
$kfilter->mediaTypeEqual = KalturaMediaType::VIDEO;
// Make sure video is done transcoding or whatever
$kfilter->status = KalturaEntryStatus::READY;
// List in descending order
$kfilter->orderBy = KalturaBaseEntryOrderBy::CREATED_AT_DESC;
// $kfilter->orderBy = KalturaBaseEntryOrderBy::CREATED_AT_ASC;
// Create pager
$pager = new KalturaFilterPager();
// choose the pageSize -- number of items per call
// choose the pageIndex -- which page we're on now (page "1" is the first page)
$pager->pageSize = 5;
$pager->pageIndex = 1;
echo "<h1>My Videos</h1>";
$result = $kclient->media->listAction($kfilter, $pager);
$count = $result->totalCount; // total number of items in the account
echo "<h1>Total: $result->totalCount Videos </h1>";
while (!empty($result->objects)) {
 echo "<h2>Page $pager->pageIndex</h2>";
 echo "<table>";
 foreach ($result->objects as $entry) {
  echo '<tr><td><img src="'.$entry->thumbnailUrl.'">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Title: '.$entry->name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="'.$entry->dataUrl.'">download</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Created on: '.date("D M j G:i:s T Y", $entry->createdAt).'</td></tr>';
 }
 echo "</table>";
 $pager->pageIndex++;
 $result = $kclient->media->listAction($kfilter, $pager);
}
?>
```

Comment: well, you don't even show us your classes - what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You increase the page number in a while block and keep rendering page after page.

```
while (!empty($result->objects)) {
  echo "<h2>Page $pager->pageIndex</h2>";
  echo "<table>";
  ...
  echo "</table>";
  $pager->pageIndex++;
  $result = $kclient->media->listAction($kfilter, $pager);
}
```

You need to remove to while loop and only render the one page the user has requested.

Comment: I appreciate that. I did understand why it was showing everything on a single page. I would really appreciate some help regarding how I might be able to begin paginating them.

Comment: You need to retrieve the page index from the request and feed that to the pager component. I'm not familiar with Kaltura, so I'm not really sure how to do this in your given use case.